# XAML Visual layer does not seem to be able to animate the Size target property

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, panel

I have a custom panel that is using the visual layer to try and animate the Offset and Size properties of each child, so they animate into new positions and new sizes.

It works fine for animating the Offset but completely ignores any attempt to animate the Size. Is it even possible to animate the Size property? Or is there something special about it that prevents it happening?

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    private HashSet<UIElement> _elements = new HashSet<UIElement>();

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size totalSize = new Size();

        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            if (!_elements.Contains(child))
            {
                Visual visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(child);
                Compositor compositor = visual.Compositor;

                ImplicitAnimationCollection implicits = compositor.CreateImplicitAnimationCollection();

                Vector3KeyFrameAnimation offsetAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
                offsetAnimation.Target = nameof(Visual.Offset);
                offsetAnimation.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(1.0f, "this.FinalValue");
                offsetAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

                Vector2KeyFrameAnimation sizeAnimation = compositor.CreateVector2KeyFrameAnimation();
                sizeAnimation.Target = nameof(Visual.Size);
                sizeAnimation.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(1.0f, "this.FinalValue");
                sizeAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

                implicits[nameof(Visual.Offset)] = offsetAnimation;
                implicits[nameof(Visual.Size)] = sizeAnimation;
                visual.ImplicitAnimations = implicits;

                _elements.Add(child);
            }

            child.Measure(availableSize);
            totalSize.Width = Math.Max(totalSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Width);
            totalSize.Height += child.DesiredSize.Height;
        }

        return totalSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        Point anchorPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Arrange(new Rect(anchorPoint, child.DesiredSize));
            anchorPoint.Y += child.DesiredSize.Height;
            anchorPoint.X += child.DesiredSize.Height / 2;
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-animate-the-size-of-a-frameworkelement) that explains how to animate the size of a framework element.

Comment: Thanks, but that uses the Framework level animation system and not the implicit animation capability of the visual layer.